# How to align Lists (ul and Li) in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css

I was wondering wether I could make unordered lists display to the middle of the page, the content stays there but the text dot stays at the side.

I have tried to use the `text-align` property in order to achieve this, although this does not give the desired effect.

```css
ul {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html "lang=eng">
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <Li></Li>
    <Li></Li>
    <Li></Li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Please note the above snippet is for demonstration purposes only.

Comment: Add width to ul {width:100px;} and write ul in center tags

Answer (score 1):

designating a fixed size for ul and making text-align to center worked if u mean like this way

```
<html>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>

<style>
    ul{
        width:100px;
        height:20px;
    }
    li{
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting a width to your ul, you may wish to keep this dynamic and instead using `margin: 0 auto` to align your unordered list to the center.

```css
ul {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <Li>1</Li>
  <Li>2</Li>
  <Li>3</Li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by add `list-style-type:none;` on style?

```css
<div>
  <ul style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial;list-style-type: none; text-align: center;">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <ul style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial;list-style-type: none; text-align: center;">
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```